# XCode 4 Optimizations

Tags: ide, xcode4

In the vein of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations Question, I would love to collect tips and tricks to make XCode4 go faster in day to day use.

Especially, I'm interested in ways to disable annoying UI animations, improve build times and getting apps under the debugger faster. Tips that reduce XCode's memory footprint as well as improve startup times are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are a collection of tiny XCode plugins that can be found [here](http://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins), which allow for many of XCode's more annoying (and often distracting) features to be disabled (including the "annoying UI animations" you mentioned).

Detailed instructions for the plugins and installation process can be found [here](http://github.com/davekeck/Xcode-4-Fixins/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable indexing (this will considerably reduce the amount of ram and CPU XCode uses)

   $ defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
2. Reduce XCode's priority (this will allow you to do other things while building)

   $ renice 10 -p PID (Where PID is XCode's Process ID )
3. [Avoid dependency checks on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533799/build-slow-on-xcode4-because-of-check-dependencies) (this will make builds faster)

Comment: Will disabling indexing cause syntax colouring stop working? Or not?